# Show/Hide previous form field entries

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, browser

I was wondering if someone knows what controls the showing of previous form field entries in a form.

So for example, if in the name field, I go to type 'John' it appears below the field. Is that a feature of the browser or is it javascript or something?

Also, if it is the browser, is there a way I can turn this off for a given form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be looking at autocomplete, if so turn it off with `autocomplete="off"` within the HTML of the relevant field:

```
<input type="text" name="firstname" autocomplete="off" />
```

References:

- [`input` element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Element/Input).

Comment: What if I just want to remove or clear the entires?

Comment: @Urasquirrel: that would be an entirely different question, and I don't think there's any way of emptying the browser's cache of suggestions, that's a client-side actionI'd imagine.

Answer (score 1):

It's made by the browser, if you're working with HTML5 you can set a attribute to the input-element to remove it.

```
<input type="text" autocomplete="off" />
```